# Type-casting arrays/vectors in Rust

Tags: arrays, vector, rust

What would be the idiomatic way of converting arrays or vectors of one type to another in Rust? The desired effect is

```
let x = ~[0 as int, 1 as int, 2 as int];
let y = vec::map(x, |&e| { e as uint });
```

but I'm not sure if the same could be achieved in a more concise fashion, similar to scalar type-casts.

I seem to fail at finding clues in the Rust manual or reference. TIA.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In general, the best you are going to get is similar to what you have (this allocates a new vector):

```
let x = vec![0, 1, 2];
let y = x.iter().map(|&e| e as u32).collect();
```

Although, if you know the bit patterns of the things you are casting between are the same (e.g. a newtype struct to the type it wraps, or casting between `uint` and `int`), you can do an in-place cast, that will not allocate a new vector (although it means that the old `x` can not be accessed):

```
let x = [0, 1, 2];
let y: [u32; 3] = unsafe { cast::transmute(x) };
```

(Note that this is `unsafe`, and can cause Bad Things to happen.)

Comment: Thank you. Going the usual functional way and using `map` will be good enough.

Comment: Looks like this answer needs an update to account for newer versions of Rust (e.g. there's no more `do` keyword, and I think you need `.iter()` and `.collect()` in there somewhere)

Comment: Not to mention that we now have proper `Box` instead of  whatever that squiggly meant before.

Comment: @huon can this be used to cast ro a vector of a larger int type?

Comment: Your example transmutes an array, which is fine, but your words imply you can transmute a vector. Which is definitely disallowed. The only valid way to do that is `from_raw_parts()`. But, better you use something like [`bytemuck`'s `cast_vec()`](https://docs.rs/bytemuck/latest/bytemuck/allocation/fn.cast_vec.html). Also note that transmuting an array **will** copy (unless the compiler optimizes that out), and transmuting a slice, while not strictly forbidden, should be replaced by pointer casts.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Rust 1.55, arrays can be converted between types concisely and safely using the `map()` method:

```rust
let x = [1, 2, 3];
let x_i64 = x.map(i64::from);
```

This is specific to arrays, and won't work on Vecs.