# Rust Vector of Traits: cast each trait

Tags: vector, casting, rust, traits

I have a problem casting a vector of traits into a vector of different traits.

Using the approach of [Type-casting arrays/vectors in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755181/type-casting-arrays-vectors-in-rust) , I basically tried the following:

```
trait ParentTrait {}

trait ChildTrait: ParentTrait {}

fn main() {
    let mut children: Vec<Box<ChildTrait>> = vec![];
    let parents = children.iter().map(|&e| e as Box<ParentTrait>);
}
```

Now this does not compile, it results in

```
error: the trait `core::kinds::Sized` is not implemented for the type `ChildTrait`
[...]
error: the trait `ParentTrait` is not implemented for the type `ChildTrait`
[...]
```

(The second errorline is buggy behaviour of the compiler, I guess?)

I tried various other flavors of References / Boxes and could not get it to work.

What am I doing wrong here,
is this even the correct approach with newer versions of rust (0.13)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Trait objects are very strange beasts.

What is a `Box<ChildTrait>`? `Box<T>` is literally a wrapper for a `*mut T`. Therefore, a `Box<ChildTrait>` wraps a `*mut ChildTrait`. Because `ChildTrait` names a trait, `ChildTrait` is an [**object type**](http://doc.rust-lang.org/reference.html#object-types). A pointer to an object type is represented by a pair of pointers: a pointer to the vtable for that trait **and only that trait**, and a pointer to the actual value.

When we inherit a trait from another trait, that doesn't mean we can obtain a pointer to the vtable for the first trait from a pointer to the vtable for the second trait. This is why the compiler complains that

```
the trait `ParentTrait` is not implemented for the type `ChildTrait`
```

We can, however, manually implement a trait for an object type. Because object types are unsized, we must first allow `ParentTrait` to be implemented for unsized types:

```
trait ParentTrait for Sized? {}
```

Then we can provide an `impl` of `ParentTrait` for the `ChildTrait` object type:

```
impl<'a> ParentTrait for ChildTrait+'a {}
```

If we try to compile now, we get different errors:

```
<anon>:9:40: 9:42 error: cannot move out of dereference of `&`-pointer
<anon>:9     let parents = children.iter().map(|&e| e as Box<ParentTrait>);
                                                ^~
<anon>:9:41: 9:42 note: attempting to move value to here
<anon>:9     let parents = children.iter().map(|&e| e as Box<ParentTrait>);
                                                 ^
<anon>:9:41: 9:42 help: to prevent the move, use `ref e` or `ref mut e` to capture value by reference
<anon>:9     let parents = children.iter().map(|&e| e as Box<ParentTrait>);
```

We can use `into_iter` instead of `iter` to consume the initial `Vec`:

```
fn main() {
    let mut children: Vec<Box<ChildTrait>> = vec![];
    let parents = children.into_iter().map(|e| e as Box<ParentTrait>);
}
```

But then we get an internal compiler error:

```
error: internal compiler error: trying to take the sizing type of ChildTrait, an unsized type
note: the compiler unexpectedly panicked. this is a bug.
note: we would appreciate a bug report: http://doc.rust-lang.org/complement-bugreport.html
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` for a backtrace
task 'rustc' panicked at 'Box<Any>', /build/rust-git/src/rust/src/libsyntax/diagnostic.rs:175
```

The same error also occurs with this code:

```
fn main() {
    let mut children: Vec<Box<ChildTrait>> = vec![];
    let parents = children.iter().map(|e| &**e as &ParentTrait);
}
```

At this point, I don't know if, after fixing the ICE, this would compile successfully or not.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation! Do you know if this is a bug that is already known? Else I would submit a new bugreport.

Comment: Confirmed that it is currently not possible to cast traits this way, but should be coming in the future.