# Can I cast between two traits?

Tags: rust, traits

Is there a way to cast from one trait to another?

I have the traits `Foo` and `Bar` and a `Vec<Box<dyn Foo>>`. I know some of the items in the `Vec` implement the `Bar` trait, but is there any way I could target them?

I don't understand if this is possible or not.

```
trait Foo {
    fn do_foo(&self);
}

trait Bar {
    fn do_bar(&self);
}

struct SomeFoo;

impl Foo for SomeFoo {
    fn do_foo(&self) {
        println!("doing foo");
    }
}

struct SomeFooBar;

impl Foo for SomeFooBar {
    fn do_foo(&self) {
        println!("doing foo");
    }
}

impl Bar for SomeFooBar {
    fn do_bar(&self) {
        println!("doing bar");
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foos: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = vec![Box::new(SomeFoo), Box::new(SomeFooBar)];

    for foo in foos {
        foo.do_foo();

        // if let Some(val) = foo.downcast_whatever::<Bar>() {
        //     val.bar();
        // }
    }
}

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b637bddc4fc923ce705e84ad1d783d4)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25246443/rust-downcasting-and-boxany

Comment: I think it's related but not exactly the same. In addition it's 1.5 years old so the chances are high that something changed about that ;)

Comment: The closest thing I found was this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27073799/rust-vector-of-traits-cast-each-trait?rq=1

But it ends with a compiler bug (unfortunately without a link) and is kind of old, too.

Comment: @Christoph Shepmaster has given you several options (and Paolo gave you the jackhammer - use wisely), but without some context about what these traits *mean* it's hard to give concrete answers about how to model the solution. The first, and most often best, instinct is an enum, but whether (and how) that's a fit for your problem is really up in the air.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

No. There is no way to cast between two unrelated traits. To understand why, we have to understand how trait objects are implemented. To start with, let's look at [`TraitObject`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/raw/struct.TraitObject.html).

`TraitObject` is a reflection of how trait objects are actually implemented. They are composed of two pointers: `data` and `vtable`. The `data` value is just a reference to the original object:

```
#![feature(raw)]

use std::{mem, raw};

trait Foo {}
impl Foo for u8 {}

fn main() {
    let i = 42u8;
    let t = &i as &dyn Foo;
    let to: raw::TraitObject = unsafe { mem::transmute(t) };

    println!("{:p}", to.data);
    println!("{:p}", &i);
}
```

`vtable` points to a table of function pointers. This table contains references to each implemented trait method, ordered by some compiler-internal manner.

For this hypothetical input

```
trait Foo {
    fn one(&self);
}

impl Foo for u8 {
    fn one(&self) { println!("u8!") }
}
```

The table is something like this pseudocode

```
const FOO_U8_VTABLE: _ = [impl_of_foo_u8_one];
```

A trait object knows a pointer to the data and a pointer to a list of methods that make up that trait. From this information, there is **no way** to get any other piece of data.

Well, *almost* no way. As you might guess, you can add a method to the vtable that returns a *different* trait object. In computer science, all problems can be solved by adding another layer of indirection (except too many layers of indirection).

See also:

- [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423)

> But couldn't the `data` part of the `TraitObject` be transmuted to the struct

Not safely, no. A trait object contains no information about the original type. All it has is a raw pointer containing an address in memory. You could *unsafely* transmute it to a `&Foo` or a `&u8` or a `&()`, but neither the compiler nor the runtime data have any idea what concrete type it originally was.

The [`Any` trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) actually does this by also tracking the type ID of the original struct. If you ask for a reference to the correct type, the trait will transmute the data pointer for you.

> Is there a pattern other than the one I described with my `FooOrBar` trait to handle such cases where we need to iterate over a bunch of trait objects but treat some of them slightly different?

- If you own these traits, then you can add `as_foo` to the `Bar` trait and vice versa.
- You could create an enum that holds either a `Box<dyn Foo>` or a `Box<dyn Bar>` and then pattern match.
- You could move the body of `bar` into the body of `foo` for that implementation.
- You could implement a third trait `Quux` where calling `<FooStruct as Quux>::quux` calls `Foo::foo` and calling `<BarStruct as Quux>::quux` calls `Bar::foo` followed by `Bar::bar`.

Comment: But couldn't the `data` part of the `TraitObject` be transmuted to the `struct` and once we have the struct we can safely cast into the other trait? 

Well, but even if that worked it won't for stable rust. So, is there a pattern other than the one I described with my `FooOrBar` trait to handle such cases where we need to iterate over a bunch of trait objects but treat some of them slightly different?

Comment: I would not that C++ also uses a v-table and stores run-time type information there on top of the regular list of virtual methods, so the use of a v-table in itself does not preclude down-casting. It is just that Rust does not store such information.

Answer (score 3):

Here is what I did.

I added an `as_bar` method to the `Foo` trait that returns an `Option<&Bar>`. I gave the trait a default implementation to return `None` so that there is little to no inconvenience for `Foo` implementers that don't bother about `Bar`.

```
trait Foo {
    fn do_foo(&self);

    fn as_bar(&self) -> Option<&dyn Bar> {
        None
    }
}
```

I overwrite that method for the `SomeFooBar` struct which implements both `Foo` and `Bar` to return `Some(self)`:

```
impl Foo for SomeFooBar {
    fn do_foo(&self) {
        println!("doing foo");
    }

    fn as_bar(&self) -> Option<&dyn Bar> {
        Some(self)
    }
}
```

Which makes the calling code look pretty much the way I want it to look.

```
fn main() {
    let foos: Vec<Box<dyn Foo>> = vec![Box::new(SomeFoo), Box::new(SomeFooBar)];

    for foo in foos {
        foo.do_foo();

        if let Some(bar) = foo.as_bar() {
            bar.do_bar();
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8b92e55d587228bb55e70ddcab6a7cb5)

I would love to see Rust improve on this part in the future, but it's a solution I can totally live with for my case.

Answer (score 2):

so... I don't think this is exactly what you want, but it's the closest I can get.

```
// first indirection: trait objects
let sf: Box<Foo> = Box::new(SomeFoo);
let sb: Box<Bar> = Box::new(SomeFooBar);

// second level of indirection: Box<Any> (Any in this case
// is the first Box with the trait object, so we have a Box<Box<Foo>>
let foos: Vec<Box<Any>> = vec![Box::new(sf), Box::new(sb)];

// downcasting to the trait objects
for foo in foos {
    match foo.downcast::<Box<Foo>>() {
        Ok(f) => f.do_foo(),
        Err(other) => {
            if let Ok(bar) = other.downcast::<Box<Bar>>() {
                    bar.do_bar();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

note that we can call `SomeFooBar` as a `Box<Bar>` only because we stored it as a `Box<Bar>` in the first place. So this is still not what you want (`SomeFooBar` is a `Foo` too, but you can't convert it to a `Box<Foo>` any longer, so we're not really converting one trait to the other)

Comment: Interesting approach but as you noted it's not exactly what I need because I have to decide for `Foo` or `Bar` but can't handle a type as being both `Foo` and `Bar` at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: there is extremely limited support for downcasting at the moment in the language.

---

The long answer is that being able to downcast is not seen as high-priority for both technical and philosophical reasons:

- from a technical stand-point, there are workarounds for most if not all situations
- from a philosophical stand-point, downcasting leads to more brittle software (as you unexpectedly start relying on implementation details)

There have been multiple proposals, and I myself [participated](https://github.com/matthieu-m/rust-poly), but for now none has been selected and it is unclear whether Rust will ever get downcasting or if it does what its limitations will be.

In the mean time, you have essentially two workarounds:

1. Use `TypeId`: each type has an associated `TypeId` value which can be queried, then you can build a type-erased container such as [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) and query whether the type it holds is a specific X. Behind the scenes `Any` will simply check the `TypeId` of this X against the `TypeId` of the value stored.
2. Create a specific `trait`, as you did.

The latter is more open-ended, and notably can be used with traits, whereas the former is limited to concrete types.

Comment: That's interesting. Can you elaborate on the `TypeId` part a bit? Maybe with a bit of code to demonstrate it, I think I haven't fully groked how that workaround is supposed to work.

Comment: @Christoph: I linked to `std::any::Any` which uses `TypeId` in the background, or you can check the github repository I linked to to see how to create your own downcasting facilities based on `TypeId`... but really I just mentioned either for completeness. `Any` does not allow downcasting, it just allows retrieving the original type, and `rust-poly` is a proof of concept. The only current generic work-around is to build downcasting in a trait, that's what Servo does.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I hope to see Rust improve on that front in the future. I updated my question with the solution that I went for in the meantime.

Comment: @Christoph: Ah! Please do not mix question and answer in the question! Instead, you can perfectly post an answer to your own question with the solution; I think the solution you chose is indeed quite idiomatic. For the record though, I am not myself a fan of downcasting (because it introduces brittleness) so I do not miss it and would quite favor never having it.

Comment: Sorry, corrected it ;) I actually don't need downcasting that often either. I'll see how I manage without it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that I found originally is to introduce a third trait `FooOrBar` with explicit converter methods and implement that for both types. It doesn't feel like the right tool for the job though.

```
trait FooOrBar {
    fn to_bar(&self) -> Option<&dyn Bar>;
    fn to_foo(&self) -> Option<&dyn Foo>;
}

impl FooOrBar for SomeFooBar {
    fn to_bar(&self) -> Option<&dyn Bar> {
        Some(self)
    }

    fn to_foo(&self) -> Option<&dyn Foo> {
        None
    }
}

impl FooOrBar for SomeFoo {
    fn to_bar(&self) -> Option<&dyn Bar> {
        None
    }

    fn to_foo(&self) -> Option<&dyn Foo> {
        Some(self)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let foos: Vec<Box<dyn FooOrBar>> = vec![Box::new(SomeFoo), Box::new(SomeFooBar)];

    for foo in foos {
        foo.to_foo().map(|foo| foo.do_foo());
        foo.to_bar().map(|foo| foo.do_bar());
    }
}
```