# Return &dyn Trait1 from Box<dyn Trait1 + Trait2>

Tags: rust

If I have a `Box<dyn Trait1 + Trait2>`, can I return a `&dyn Trait1` ?

To give some context, I am trying to implement a (specialised) graph in rust. This `SpecialisedGraph` needs some standard graph algorithms, and I would like to implement these using the `Graph` trait that could be shared across several graph types but this code is not compiling:

```
trait Node {
    //...
}

trait Graph {
    fn get_node(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&dyn Node>;
}

trait SpecialisedNode {
    //...
}

trait SpecialisedGraphNode: SpecialisedNode + Node {}

struct SpecialisedGraph {
    nodes: HashMap<String, Box<dyn SpecialisedGraphNode>>
}

impl Graph for SpecialisedGraph {
    fn get_node(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&dyn Node> {
        match self.nodes.get(key) {
            Some(node) => Some(&(**node)),
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

With error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src\main.rs:25:32
   |
25 |             Some(node) => Some(&(**node)),
   |                                ^^^^^^^^^ expected trait `Node`, found trait `SpecialisedGraphNode`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&dyn Node`
              found reference `&dyn SpecialisedGraphNode`
```

EDIT: I have edited the question to reflect the comments

EDIT2: Found the answer to my question using the link  [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28632968/why-doesnt-rust-support-trait-object-upcasting) provided by Shepmaster.

The updated code below now works, thanks all.

```
trait AsNode {
    fn as_node(&self) -> &dyn Node;
}

trait Node : AsNode {
    //...
}

impl<T: Node> AsNode for T {
    fn as_node(&self) -> &dyn Node {
        self
    }
}

trait Graph {
    fn get_node(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&dyn Node>;
}

trait SpecialisedNode : Node {
    //...
}

struct SpecialisedGraph {
    nodes: HashMap<String, Box<dyn SpecialisedNode>>
}

impl Graph for SpecialisedGraph {
    fn get_node(&self, key: &str) -> Option<&dyn Node> {
        match self.nodes.get(key) {
            Some(node) => Some(node.as_node()),
            None => None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [Can I cast between two traits?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34419561/155423); [Why doesn't Rust support trait object upcasting?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28632968/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: See also [Why is it discouraged to accept a reference to a String (&String), Vec (&Vec), or Box (&Box) as a function argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40006219/155423) — returning `&Box<T>` is non-idiomatic.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that `&Box<T>` wasn't idiomatic! My traits are related to each other though, when I have a `SpecialisedGraphNode` I know that it implements `Node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. A `HashMap<String, Box<dyn SpecialisedGraphNode>` is not a `HashMap<String, Box<dyn Node>`, so you can't form a reference of that type to it. If you do it with unsafe code, you invoke undefined behavior, because those boxes don't have the same data.

I also think your feeling is wrong - at least Java, C++ and C# (to name the most common statically typed OO languages) don't let you do that either. (C# lets you do something similar with `IReadOnlyDictionary` and covariant generic arguments to interfaces in general. But not for concrete types.)

You probably need to rethink your `Graph` trait. Does it really have to give access to the nodes as a hash map? Maybe it could simply provide a function to look up a node, and return that as a `&dyn Node`?

Comment: Thanks @Sebastian-Redl, that's helpful. I ran into another issue so I just edited my question to reflect your comments