# Calling Rust from R: Error "Expected a vector type."

Tags: r, rust, extendr, rextendr

I'm trying to learn how to connect Rust and R (in addition to learning Rust itself) using the `rextendr` R package and the `extendr` Rust crate. I came across the error `Expected a vector type.` when I use `:` in the input of my R function.

Below is an example with a simple function that returns `TRUE` if all the values in the input vector are positive, and `FALSE` otherwise. It seems to work fine when I use `c()` in the input, but not when I use `:`.

```r
library(rextendr)

# create a Rust function that checks if all values in the input are
# greater than 0
rust_function(
  "fn all_positive(input: &[f64]) -> bool {
      let mut out = true;
      for i in input.iter() {
        if *i <= 0.0 {
          out = false;
          break
        }  
      }
      out
  }"
)
#> ℹ build directory: '/tmp/RtmpeoMSEH/file7f971642e99e'
#> ✔ Writing '/tmp/RtmpeoMSEH/file7f971642e99e/target/extendr_wrappers.R'.

# call it from R
all_positive(c(1, 2, 3))
#> [1] TRUE

all_positive(c(0, 1, 2))
#> [1] FALSE

all_positive(1:3)
#> Error in all_positive(1:3): Expected a vector type.
```

Why is that and how can I fix it?

*PS: since I'm beginning in Rust, feel free to mention any other error/non-idiomatic things in the Rust code.*

Comment: In R, `1:3` isn't the exact same as `c(1,2,3)`. The former is called an ALTREP. You can read more about them here: https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~luke/talks/uiowa-2018.pdf. Do you just always want to expand ALTREP into vectors for your function? Or did you want to have a special implementation for such objects?

Comment: I didn't know this difference so I'm not sure how to handle it. Let's say that I want to expand ALTREP into vectors (but if it doesn't add too much work to make a special implementation for ALTREP, I think it would be useful to see the difference between the two ways. Otherwise maybe I'll ask another question). Thank you for the link anyway

Comment: I would guess `all_positive(as.vector(1:3))` would work. I'm not sure what the rust type signature would be.

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. But in any case, I'd rather fix this on the Rust side so that R users don't need to tweak it by themselves (for example `all(1:3 > 0)` works fine)

Comment: But `seq(1,3)` does not. And on my machine `all_positive( all(1:3 > 0) )` throws an error as well. So doe `all_positive(as.vector(1:3))`

Comment: @IRTFM Yes it's normal that `all_positive(all(1:3 > 0))` doesn't work, I just wanted to mention that `all(1:3 > 0)` works fine in R so I'd like `all_positive(1:3)` to work as well.

Comment: In my case `all_positive(as.numeric(1:3))` does work. `all_positive(c(1L, 2L, 3L))` or `all_positive(as.integer(c(1, 2, 3)))` do not work. For your function you have to use *numeric* and not *integer* as an input as you have defined the input as `&[f64]`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### You need a Rust function that accepts both `integer` and `numeric` types

`1:3` creates an `integer` vector and `c(1,2,3)` creates a `numeric` vector. The function in your example expects `f64`, i.e. `numeric` input, so does not like `1:3` (which would be `i32`). You can write a function that accepts both by making your function parameter an [`Robj`](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/extendr_api/robj/index.html), e.g.

```r
rextendr::rust_function(
    "fn all_positive(input: Robj) -> extendr_api::scalar::Rbool {
    let float_vec: Option<Vec<f64>> = input.as_real_vector();
    let int_vec: Option<Vec<i32>> = input.as_integer_vector();

    match float_vec {
        Some(vec) => return extendr_api::scalar::Rbool::from_bool(vec.iter().all(|x: &f64| x > &0.0)),
        None => (),
    }

    match int_vec {
        Some(vec) => return extendr_api::scalar::Rbool::from_bool(vec.iter().all(|x: &i32| x > &0)),
        None => (),
    }
    extendr_api::scalar::Rbool::na_value()
}
"
)
```

*Edit: now this returns an* `Rbool` *rather than a Rust* `bool` *, so that if you call the function with a non-numeric type, e.g. a character vector, it can return* `NA_logical_`.

### More detail

That was the tl;dr. Here is more info. There are three factors at play here:

1. The `:` operator means R creates an `integer` rather than a `numeric` vector.
2. Rust is a statically typed language. The function defined in your question expects an array slice of `f64` values. More generally, Rust requires function parameters to be an explicit type , or a [generic](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-01-syntax.html) with shared traits.
3. `extendr` [does not support generics](https://github.com/extendr/extendr/issues/427), by design.

#### `integer` vs `numeric`: what a difference a `:` makes

As pointed out in the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75608152/calling-rust-from-r-error-expected-a-vector-type/75645902?noredirect=1#comment133455112_75645902) by Dirk Eddelbuettel, by convention the `:` operator implies an integer vector (even before [`ALTREP`](https://www.brodieg.com/2019/02/18/an-unofficial-reference-for-internal-inspect/)):

```r
class(c(1,2,3)) # numeric
class(1:3) # integer
```

We can peek at the underlying C representation using the [`lobstr`](https://www.tidyverse.org/blog/2018/12/lobstr/) package:

```r
lobstr::sxp(1:3) 
# <INTSXP[3]> (altrep named:65535)

lobstr::sxp(c(1,2,3)) 
#  <REALSXP[3]> (named:2)
```

As set out in [R Internals](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-ints.html), an `INTSXP` is a block of C `int` values. A `REALSXP` is a block of C `double` values.

#### Translating `INTSXP` and `REALSXP` into the Rust world

We can use the `extendr-api`, `extendr-engine` and `extendr-macros` crates (`v.0.4.0`) to see directly from Rust how `extendr` maps R types, using the [`R!` macro](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/extendr_api/macro.R.html):

```rust
fn main() {
    test! {

    let r_vec = R!("c(1,2,3)")?;
    let r_altrep = R!("1:3")?;

    println!("{}", Robj::is_altrep(&r_altrep)); // true

    println!("{:?}", r_altrep); // [1,2,3]
    println!("{:?}", r_vec); // [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

    }
}
```

This quick-and-dirty debug print confirms that the `1:3` object is printed as a collection of integers ([`i32`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.i32.html)), whereas `c(1,2,3)` is printed as floats, i.e. [`f64`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.f64.html) in the Rust world.

#### Generics

Now we know that we are dealing with different types, my temptation was to do something like:

```rust
fn all_positive_iter<I>(r_obj: I) -> bool
where
    I: IntoIterator,
{
   // some code here
}
```

However - although this will compile in Rust, it will not compile as an exported `extendr` function.

#### Creating a Rust function that takes `integer` and `numeric` types

An `extendr` Github issue about the lack of generics support [suggests](https://github.com/extendr/extendr/issues/427) creating a Rust function which takes an [`Robj`](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/extendr_api/robj/index.html), rather than a primitive Rust type, and resolving this in Rust.  In this case, we can use the [`Robj::as_integer_vector()`](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/extendr_api/robj/struct.Robj.html#method.as_integer_vector) and [`Robj::as_real_vector`](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/extendr_api/robj/struct.Robj.html#method.as_real_vector) methods.

The documentation for these seems to be in progress but we can see from the [source](https://extendr.github.io/extendr/src/extendr_api/robj/mod.rs.html#480-482) that they return the [`Option<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/) type, i.e. either `Some(<T>)` or `None`. We can use the `match` construct to try to convert what we receive from R into both an integer and a float vector, and only do the thing we want to do when we get `Some()` type.

As an aside, one of the great things about Rust is it's quite similar to R in often being able to use iterators rather than loops. I think we can do this with the main part of your code. We can use code very similar to the [`iter.all()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.all) docs:

```rust
let a = [1, 2, 3];

assert!(a.iter().all(|&x| x > 0));
```

You could also [type cast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16755181/type-casting-arrays-vectors-in-rust) the `i32` to `f64` if you don't want to have two comparisons, though as we can chain the `.iter()` in the `match` statements I haven't bothered.

This will then allow us to call the function defined at the start for both `1:3` and `c(1,2,3)`.

```r
all_positive(c(1, 2, 3))
#> [1] TRUE

all_positive(c(0, 1, 2))
#> [1] FALSE

all_positive(1:3)
#> [1] TRUE
```

Comment: The comment is partially wrong. Consider `all.equal(1:3, c(1L,2L,3L))` -- this was always true, even before ALTREP and still is (also holds for `identical`). The `:` by convention impies `int` as a sequence makes no sense for `double`.  The rest of the discussion has little to do with Rust specifically: it is exactly the same with other statically-typed languages as a _e.g._ C and C++.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel thanks I didn't realise that - I have updated the answer. `extendr` and `rextendr` are much less mature and nowhere near as well-documented as `Rcpp` yet. It wasn't at all obvious to me how to write a Rust function that accepts R `integer` or `numeric` vectors without using generics, so I hope the discussion around that is useful to others.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. I will wait before accepting or giving the bounty to see if other people come with different approaches (especially from people who have more experience in Rust). But I appreciate all the links and explanations

Comment: @bretauv it would be great if there were more answers from experienced Rustaceans. Currently yours seems to be the only question with the `extendr` tag on SO. The Rust community seems amazing but at the moment I don't know where to find responses to questions about calling Rust code from R. Certainly it's nothing like the `Rcpp` community yet - which is a shame because I think Rust is a much nicer language than C++.

Comment: @SamR I asked `extendr` devs and they said your current answer is fine

Answer (score 3):

There are some features in the unreleased version of `{extendr}` and `{extendr}` that could help you. Unfortunately, this made me realize that `extendr` still lacks a couple of very important things (we are on it already).

```
# Using dev rextendr from github

rextendr::rust_source(
    code = "
    use either::Either::{self, Left, Right};
    #[extendr(use_try_from = true)]
    fn all_positive(input: Either<Integers, Doubles>) -> bool {
      match input {
        Left(ints) => ints.iter().all(|x| <Option<i32>>::from(x).unwrap_or(-1i32) >= 0i32),
        Right(dbls) => dbls.iter().all(|x| <Option<f64>>::from(x).unwrap_or(-1f64) >= 0f64),
      }
    }",
    features = "either", # Enable `extendr-api` feature `either`
    use_dev_extendr = TRUE, # Use `extendr-api` from github
    dependencies = list(either = "*"), # Reference `either` crate
)
#> Warning: Found unknown `extendr` feature: "either".
#> i Are you using a development version of `extendr`?
#> i build directory: 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeOiZKI/file4a7c70034e74'
#> v Writing 'C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpeOiZKI/file4a7c70034e74/target/extendr_wrappers.R'

1:10 |> all_positive()
#> [1] TRUE
(-1 * 1:10) |> all_positive()
#> [1] FALSE

c(1, 2, 3, 5.5) |> all_positive()
#> [1] TRUE
c(1, 2, 3, -5.5) |> all_positive()
#> [1] FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2023-03-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

The `use_try_from` function option is already coming to dev `{rextendr}`, but the lack of comparison implemented for `Rint` and `Rfloat` makes lambdas ugly. This will be soon tackled as well.

Bonus thing: `Integers` and `Doubles` are thin wrappers around `Robj` (`SEXP`), so there is no extra memory copying on Rust side (apart from allocating a couple of structs to store `SEXP`). And it consumes altrep without allocation as well!

Comment: This is nice. What is the advantage of [`Integers`](https://docs.rs/extendr-api/latest/extendr_api/wrapper/integers/struct.Integers.html) over `Robj::as_integer_vector()`? Is it the allocation? Thanks for your work on `extendr`, it seems like an awesome tool.

Comment: Yep, allocation goes first. `Integers` contains an `SEXP` + some useful trait implementations, while `as_integer_vector()` retrieves underlying `&[i32]` (unsafely) and then copies it to `Vec<i32>`. `Integers`  is an iterable with an `Item` type `Rint`, which is an `NA`-aware wrapper around `i32`. Basically, `Integers` knows everything about R types and does not allow you to shoot yourself in the foot. `as_integer_vector()` will force any ALTREP to materialize, while `Integers` can be just iterated over. Oh, and you can collect into `Integers` from iterators as well!

Comment: To clarify, you can always just use `Either<Vec<i32>, Vec<f64>>` if you don't care that much about NA-safety or memory allocation
```r
rextendr::rust_source(
    code = "
    use either::Either::{self, Left, Right};
    #[extendr(use_try_from = true)]
    fn all_positive(input: Either<Vec<i32>, Vec<f64>>) -> bool {
      match input {
        Left(ints) => ints.iter().all(|x| *x >= 0i32),
        Right(dbls) => dbls.iter().all(|x| *x >= 0f64),
      }
    }",
    features = "either",
    use_dev_extendr = TRUE,
    dependencies = list(either = "*"),
)
```

Comment: That's awesome thanks. I definitely care about memory allocation (I arrived at learning Rust after moving from Python `pandas` to `polars`). I would prefer memory safety given the option. It's quite hard to know what is safe and what isn't - even looking at the `impl Integers` source there are some `unsafe` blocks.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with about everything SamR writes. Some differences of preference:

- match on `robj.rtype()` before handling `Robj`
- add in some error handling for wrong / not supported types.
- use the is.na() method to test NA encoding before reading the raw value

I acidentially wrote not a `all_positive` but a vectorized version `is_positive` but same same. All code examples can be found in [this template repository](https://github.com/sorhawell/hello_positive/blob/main/src/rust/src/lib.rs)

```rust
#[extendr]
fn is_positive(robj: Robj) -> Result<Robj> {
    use extendr_api::prelude::Rtype;
    match robj.rtype() {
        Rtype::Doubles => {
            let doubles: Doubles = robj.try_into().unwrap();
            let bool_vector_robj = doubles
                .iter()
                .map(|rfloat: Rfloat| match &rfloat {
                    _ if rfloat.is_na() => None,
                    _ if rfloat.0 > 0.0 => Some(true),
                    _ => Some(false),
                })
                .collect_robj();
            Ok(bool_vector_robj)
        }
        Rtype::Integers => {
            let doubles: Integers = robj.try_into().unwrap();
            let bool_vector_robj = doubles
                .iter()
                .map(|rint: Rint| match &rint {
                    _ if rint.is_na() => None,
                    _ if rint.0 > 0 => Some(true),
                    _ => Some(false),
                })
                .collect_robj();
            Ok(bool_vector_robj)
        }
        _ => Err(format!("this input type is not yet supported: {:?}", robj))
            .map_err(|err| extendr_api::Error::TypeMismatch(err.into())),
    }
}
```

#### An opinion on generics....

Generic functions is a compile-time concept and it does not to me make much sense that extendr should support that for incomming Robj's, which are as runtime-like as it gets. On the other hand when returning `T` type to R from rust it makes a lot of sense to use generics to funnel many types into an `Robj` or `List`.  An example, extendr will currently unwrap any `Err(E)` returned to R resulting in a panic. Using the following  generic can caputure `Result<T,E>`and convert it into an R `List`

```rust
use extendr_api::{list, Attributes, Conversions, IntoRobj};
pub fn r_result_list<T, E>(result: std::result::Result<T, E>) -> list::List
where
    T: IntoRobj,
    E: std::fmt::Display,
{
    match result {
        Ok(x) => list!(ok = x.into_robj(), err = extendr_api::NULL),
        Err(x) => list!(ok = extendr_api::NULL, err = x.to_string()),
    }
    .set_class(&["rust_result"])
    .unwrap_or_default()
    .as_list()
    .unwrap_or_default()
}
```

#### user 'tharum' on [extendr discord](https://discord.gg/7hmApuc) had bid on `all_positive` which I like to steal :)

```rust
#[extendr(use_try_from = true)]
fn all_positive(robj: Robj) -> Rbool {
    match robj.rtype() {
        Rtype::Integers => {
            let integers = Integers::try_from(robj).unwrap();
            let bool = integers.iter().any(|x| x.is_na());
            if bool {
                return Rbool::na_value();
            }
            let bool = integers.iter().all(|x| x.0 > 0);
            Rbool::from_bool(bool)
        }
        Rtype::Doubles => {
            let doubles = Doubles::try_from(robj).unwrap();
            let bool = doubles.iter().any(|x| x.is_na());
            if bool {
                return Rbool::na_value();
            }
            let bool = doubles.iter().all(|x| x.0 > 0.);
            Rbool::from_bool(bool)
        }
        _ => panic!(),
    }
}
```

Comment: I get an error with the first code chunk: `this type alias takes 1 generic argument but 2 generic arguments were supplied`

Comment: oh it is the Result type war.  I implicitly swear to `std::result::Result` I will fix. How about now?

Comment: ```the trait `ToVectorValue` is not implemented for `Result<extendr_api::Robj, String>```(sorry if I'm missing sth obvious)

Comment: Your right, I had more custom code running. That is why I should always start from helloextendr I made full tempated example here https://github.com/sorhawell/hello_positive/blob/main/src/rust/src/lib.rs

Comment: just panic! as tharum does is also fine, because extendr does not yet support any other error handling ... yet

Comment: These are both really nice solutions. I think you're right about matching on `robj.rtype()`, and the `map` and `collect` to handle `NA` in vectors is what I hope my Rust code starts to look like once I've written more of it!